# Array.each outputs all methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

Why would...

```
for(var k in this.errors) {
        $('error_list').insert({
            bottom: new Element('li').update(k + ' :'+this.errors[k])
        })
    }
```

...output put all Prototype enumerable methods, plus what I've added to the array?

I'm building an associative array:

```
this.errors['email'] = 'Your email is invalid';
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have real associative arrays. You're setting properties of the array (which is legal), but JavaScript doesn't have special methods for this usage. It's better to use objects than arrays for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may prevent this using **hasOwnProperty**:

```
for(var k in this.errors) {
    if (this.errors.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        $('error_list').insert({
            bottom: new Element('li').update(k + ' :'+this.errors[k])
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "hasOwnProperty" to guard against this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$H(this.errors).each(function(error) {
    $('error_list').insert({
        bottom: new Element('li').update(error.key + ': ' + error.value)
    })
})
```